# Quality Gate status with Jenkins pipeline not working

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

While checking quality gate status in pipeine, getting following error.

Pipeline Code is below

```
    stage('SonarQube') {
      // Run the maven build
            dir("xyz_7.6_Trunk/xyz-services"){


                sh ' mvn -f pom.xml clean install -Dapp.server=jboss org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.11.135.66:9000 -Dsonar.scm.disabled=True -U' 

            }
            }

stage('Quality Gate') {
timeout(time: 1, unit: ‘HOURS’) {
def qg = waitForQualityGate()
if (qg.status != ‘OK’) {
error “Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}”
}
}
}
```

Error log is below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'Time' 'HOURS' found among steps [acceptGitLabMR, addBadge, addErrorBadge, addGitLabMRComment, addHtmlBadge, addInfoBadge, addShortText, addWarningBadge, ansiblePlaybook, ansibleTower, ansibleVault, archive, artifactPromotion, bat, build, catchError, checkout, createSummary, deleteDir, dir, dockerFingerprintFrom, dockerFingerprintRun, dockerNode, ec2, echo, emailext, emailextrecipients, envVarsForTool, error, fileExists, getContext, git, gitChangelog, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, input, isUnix, junit, library, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, nexusArtifactUploader, nexusPolicyEvaluation, nexusPublisher, node, parallel, powershell, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, removeBadges,
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you use scripted pipeline, so the syntax should be fine.

`timeout` functionality is implemented in `Pipeline: Basic Steps` plugin (part of `Pipeline` plugin). That's why I think that you need to reinstall those plugins and the issue should be fixed. Anyway, please check again the [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38106655/10721592) of the `timeout` step.

Comment: I have tried different syntaxs  for timeout. nothing is working.    Pipeline: Basic Steps plugin is installed.. eventhough nt working.