# timeout for node allocation in Jenkins using Groovy-Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, timeout, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Question: I need to set 2 hrs time for Node Allocation, Once Node is allocated within time limit, Build should continue, If node is not allocated within time frame, Build should Aboarted.

I tried with timeout function, But in these, If node is allocated, once the time limit is reached then build is aborted in mid of exection.

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
timeout(time:2, unit: 'HOURS'){ 
node('Slave_Node') {
   // Will run on the slave

}
}
```

In console it will print during waiting like, 
"Waiting for next available executor on 'Slave_Node'"

Once the node is allocated, 
"Running on Slave_Node"

Can suggest Implementation plz.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
timeout(activity: true, time: 2, unit: 'HOURS') {
    node('Slave_Node') {
      // Will run on the slave
    }
}
```

The `activity: true` will timeout after no activity in logs for the defined block instead of absolute duration.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem which was inelegantly stated.  So imagine... I have one node to do X, and that is the agent I am waiting on. I wait 1.5 hours, and then get it. Now I have 0.5 hours left to finish the actual work, but it will take 1.5 hours.  Moreover, the actual work might have a LONG phase where it doesn't output anything... and get killed by inactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which I believe works standalone - though be careful as it may not be COMPLETE.  I was not able to turn this into a "getNode()" library function to make it portable and reusable.

```
wait_for_node = 120 // minutes
waitNode_mS = wait_for_node * 60 * 1000        // minutes into milliseconds
got_a_node = false
targetLabel = 'DESIRED_AGENT'
bodytimeout = 120 // minutes 

parallel waitfor: {
    if (waitNode_mS > 0) {
        startms = System.currentTimeMillis()
        waitUntil(initialRecurrencePeriod: 5000, quiet: true)
            { got_a_node || ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startms) > waitNode_mS) } // end waitUntil
        if (!got_a_node) {
            error "ABORTING: Failed to get $targetLabel in $wait_for_node minutes"
        } else {
            echo "Got a $targetLabel - Exiting waitfor"
        }
    } else {
        echo "WARNING: MAY wait FOREVER."
    }// if time argument = 0, exit cleanly and thus will wait indefinitely
}, executeon: {
    node(targetLabel) {
        got_a_node = true
        try {
            timeout(time: bodytimeout, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                // -------------------------------
                // MAIN BODY: DO THE WORK IN HERE
                // -------------------------------
            } // end bodyTimeout
        } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
            throw (e)
        } finally {
            // When leaving this node, clean up the workspace.
            deleteDir()
        } // try/catch/finally executing on node
    } // exit node(targetLabel)
}, failFast: true
```

Notes about this solution:

- The two maximum times are selected with the `wait_for_node` (minutes) and `bodytimeout` (minutes) values.
- Use a `parallel` step where the `waitfor` leg uses a `waitUntil` step.
- If the waitUntil (which brute force watches the system clock) exits, it all halts due to the fact that it throws an error and the parallel has  `failFast: true`
- if `wait_for_node` is set to zero it will wait forever to get the node. (Legacy behavior)
- There may be race conditions. For example if the `waitfor` time is reached and the node is allocated simultaneously it will abort the MAIN BODY.
- The inner (MAIN BODY) work is wrapped in a `timeout()` step.
- The inner `waitUntil` isn't particularly efficient. The longest it actually waits at one interval is 30 seconds as it was intended for short waits.

Comment: Oh, and the "FlowInterruptedException" encapsulates more than just the TimeOut, unfortunately.  It also includes a user request to abort, an abort of the node, and an interruption due to a milestone step being reached. BUT you cannot tell which because in the groovy sandbox, you can't inspect the cause.