# How to change default timeout in Jenkins pipeline script for cloning git repo

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I was successfully able to build in Jenkins by using the below Script till yesterday. But suddenly from today I am not able to build the project. I am getting timeout while cloning the project from GIT.

**Pipeline script :**

```
stages {
  stage ('Initialize') {
    steps {
      git url: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/gitlab/tata-comm-oss/oss-fe.git',
          credentialsId: 'xxxx-xxx-xx-xxxxxx',
          branch: 'alpha_06_1'
    }
  }
}
```

**I am getting below error.**

ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes

ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'

**How to increase the timeout for git fetch (not general timeout) in my pipeline script mentioned above so that jenkins can clone the project from GIT.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a timeout step to Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096004/how-to-add-a-timeout-step-to-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: No Chris, I want to increase the timeout for git fetch / clone. No general timeout.

Comment: Instead of `git` try using `checkout` which also supports git. You can generate the exact pipeline command at `http://<your_jenkins>/pipeline-syntax/`, look for "Advanced checkout behaviors".