# How do I stop Jenkins from stalling when an agent is turned off?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins agents are normal workstations that can be turned off. If this happens during a job, I expect Jenkins to fail that job. Instead, the job stalls indefinitely, even after the agent comes back. How do I make it fail instead? Restarting from the last step would be even better, but that is very much a nice to have.

The last log message is

> Cannot contact someagent: java.lang.InterruptedException

When I abort the stallling job, I get

> Aborted by admin
> Sending interrupt signal to process
> Click here to forcibly terminate running steps
> After 20s process did not stop

What process did not stop? Nothing can possibly be running on the agent at this point.

Jenkins version is latest LTS, the job is a declarative pipeline that invokes PowerShell scripts. An excerpt:

```
stage('Build')
{
    steps
    {
        powershell '. Tools\\Build\\Build.ps1 -version $env:VERSION'
    }
}
stage('Package')
{
    steps
    {
        powershell '. Tools\\Build\\Package.ps1 -artifact $env:ARTIFACT'
        archiveArtifacts ARTIFACT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins Plugin [Pipeline: Basic Steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps/) offers a step called [timeout](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#timeout-enforce-time-limit) that might interest you.

It can be applied to a single stage, or to the whole pipeline.

Here is an example using the Scripted Syntax:

```
timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES) {
    node {
      stage('test') { ... }
    }
}
```

If you are using the Declarative Syntax, the `timeout` option declared at the top-level agent only takes effect *after* the agent becomes available, which is not what you are trying to achieve. Instead, you can workaround it by using `agent none` at the top level and specify your agent for each stage.
This phenomenon is actually described in [the documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#differences-between-top-and-stage-level).

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    options {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') 
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            agent { label 'my-label' }
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See also this other thread: [How to add a timeout step to Jenkins Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096004/how-to-add-a-timeout-step-to-jenkins-pipeline)